# How to get second MIN value or cross column MIN value in PowerPivot?

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have an interesting table and i cant figure it out how to get 2nd minimum value or like something operation. Here is an example style of my table:

```
 Column1   Column2   Column3
   A          A          0
   A          C         11
   A          D          7
   B          X         11
   B          B          0
   A          E          5
   B          Y         17
   A          F          4
```

I need to find minimum value for each A or B (from Column1) in Column3. But A=A (column1=column2) or B=B rows should not include in this MIN calculation. But found value for A should shown on row A=A or min value for B should shown on B=B row.

Also tryed this calculations:

IF([Column1]<>[Column2],CALCULATE(**MIN**([Column3]),ALL(myTable),myTable[Column2]=EARLIER(myTable[Column2])),0)  --> returning same values from Column3 for each row.

IF([Column1]=[Column2],CALCULATE(**MIN**([Column3]),ALL(myTable),myTable[Column2]=EARLIER(myTable[Column2])),0)  --> returning min values from Column3 for each A=A or B=B rows correctly. A=A or B=B rows contain data as value is 0. if i change it to 1, it returns 1 for this calculation. But i need other rows min value.

IF([Column1]=[Column2],CALCULATE(**MAX**([Column3]),ALL(myTable),myTable[Column1]=EARLIER(myTable[Column1])),0)  --> this calculation works like a charm for MAX value. Because highest values will be in other rows always.

P.S: A=A or B=B rows default value is always 0 in Column3.

im stuck at this point =/ Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use (in a calculated column):

```
=CALCULATE(MIN([Column3]),FILTER(myTable,myTable[Column1]=EARLIER(myTable[Column1])),myTable[bColumn])
```

where myTable[bColumn] is the calculated column

```
=myTable[Column1]<>myTable[Column2]
```

If you want the formula in a measure instead of a calculated column, use:

=CALCULATE(MIN([Column3]),FILTER(ALL(myTable),COUNTROWS(FILTER(myTable,myTable[Column1]=EARLIER(myTable[Column1])))),myTable[bColumn])

HTH!

Comment: Sorry about my late answer =/ it works like a charm. But measure giving an error. Probably formula contain more than one value type. but 2 column example works good. Thank you.